# How do I get my content slideshow to reset its auto-scroll timer after a click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a content slideshow -
currently on http://harddrive.co.za/internet-solutions-provider/

**Here is the javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  setInterval(function() {
    moveRight();
  }, 8000);
  var slideCount = $('#slider-isp ul li').length;
  var slideWidth = $('#slider-isp ul li').width();
  var slideHeight = $('#slider-isp ul li').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
  $('#slider-isp').css({
    width: slideWidth,
    height: slideHeight
  });

  $('#slider-isp ul').css({
    width: sliderUlWidth,
    marginLeft: -slideWidth
  });
  $('#slider-isp ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider-isp ul');
  function moveLeft() {
    $('#slider-isp ul').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 1000, function() {
      $('#slider-isp ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider-isp ul');
      $('#slider-isp ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  function moveRight() {
    $('#slider-isp ul').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 1000, function() {
      $('#slider-isp ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider-isp ul');
      $('#slider-isp ul').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  $('a.control_prev').click(function() {
    moveLeft();
  });

  $('a.control_next').click(function() {
    moveRight();
  });
});
```

I have looked at another post for answers
[How do I get my image slider to reset its auto-scroll timer after a click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887786/how-do-i-get-my-image-slider-to-reset-its-auto-scroll-timer-after-a-click)

I want to apply something similar
without destroying my code

Please Help

Comment: Please provide a fiddle that reproduces the problem. It is easier for everyone that way.

Comment: OK I will try, haven't done one before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we don't have a verifiable example here, I can suggest the following steps:

- Save your `setInterval` into a variable.
- On a click event, clear that interval (so it doesn't execute anymore).
- Set the interval again on the same variable.

This will make sure, the same interval will pass after your click.

However, this will require to change your code a bit (not tested, as I don't have the HTML for it):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    
    // save the timer
    var tick = setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
        }, 8000);

        var slideCount = $('#slider-isp ul li').length;
        var slideWidth = $('#slider-isp ul li').width();
        var slideHeight = $('#slider-isp ul li').height();
        var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

        $('#slider-isp').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

        $('#slider-isp ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

        $('#slider-isp ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider-isp ul');

        function moveLeft() {
            $('#slider-isp ul').animate({
                left: + slideWidth
            }, 1000, function () {
                $('#slider-isp ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider-isp ul');
                $('#slider-isp ul').css('left', '');
            });
        };

        function moveRight() {
            $('#slider-isp ul').animate({
                left: - slideWidth
            }, 1000, function () {
                $('#slider-isp ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider-isp ul');
                $('#slider-isp ul').css('left', '');
            });
        };

        $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
            clearInterval(tick); // discard the timer
            moveLeft(); // do the intended stuff for click
            
            // set the timer again
            tick = setInterval(function () {
              moveRight();
              }, 8000);
        });

        $('a.control_next').click(function () {
            clearInterval(tick); // discard the timer
            moveRight(); // do the intended stuff for click
            
            // set the timer again
            tick = setInterval(function () {
              moveRight();
              }, 8000);
        });

    });
```

Comment: Thank you @beerwin, I will apply this code and try to see what happens. Still going to try the fiddle thing, to make it easier.

Comment: You can even use StackOverflow code snippets: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

It works like JsFiddle, it;s just inside this very SO site.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I will try "StackOverflow code snippets". I am struggling with JSFiddle.

Comment: Every time you make a change, you click Run (all these stuff work the same way).

Comment: you are a legend! Looks like its working :-) Enjoy the rest of your day, man!